# User reporting PayPal encrypted payment error on my site

Tags: php, encryption, paypal

A user has just sent me a screenshot of a PayPal error he got when trying to make a purchase on my site:

> **Error Detected**
>
> The seller accepts encrypted website payments only. you cannot pay the seller through un-encrypted buttons. please contact your seller for more details.

I do encrypt everything, to prevent people from maliciously manipulating items to have lower prices etc.  I've not changed any code on the site relating to this for a year or more.

I've put the exact items he has in his cart in my own cart and been able to make the purchase with no such errors.

It seems to be working for everyone else, too. I've even had purchases come in *since* this error was reported.

What might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: If you use the encrypted and protected PayPal Payments Standard button, then it's all good and the user just broke it.

Comment: What action might have caused it to break though?  An over-zealous virus scanner maybe?

Comment: Did you check if you can reproduce this?

Comment: I did, and I can't.  I've put the exact items he has in his cart in my own cart and been able to make the purchase with no such errors.

I'm worried it's down to a certificate expiring or similar and my laptop has cached something and as a new visitor he's had no such luck?

Comment: I tried in my normal browser, in a private window, and finally using a browser I never use; IE :)

Comment: You could ask your friends to check if they got the same error. If not then I would say that the user just did a mistake.

Comment: He says he's tried it on a computer and on his phone, and had the same error on both.